# Variables not being fwritten

Tags: php, forms, fopen, str-replace, fwrite

I've been trying to create a form that creates a ticket in the form of HTML to easily organize things and view the issue, however every time I try to test this, it only shows the variable as `$variable` here is the script that I am using in order to try and make this work:

```
function ip(){if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){$ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];}else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){$ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];}else{$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];}return $ip;}
$ip = ip();

$date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s A");
$emailField = $_GET['Email'];
$issue = $_GET['issue'];
$ticketField = $_GET['Ticket'];
$ip = $ip;
$date = $date;
$file = 'admin/logs.php';
$lines = file($file);
$all_lines = implode('',$lines);
$entry = str_replace('<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">endtable()</script><script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">copyright()</script>','  <tr>
    <td><div id="logleft"></div></td>
    <td><div id="logmid"><center>$emailField</center></div></td>
    <td><div id="logmid"><center>$ip</center></div></td>
    <td><div id="logmid"><center>$issueField</center></div></td>
    <td><div id="logmid"><center>$ticketField</center></div></td>
    <td><div id="logright"></div></td>
</tr>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">endtable()</script><script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">copyright()</script>',$all_lines);
$fp = fopen($file,'w'); 
$fw = fwrite($fp,$entry);
fclose($fp);
```

I have made sure that the form action is GET and not POST, however nothing is working, it is still displaying the variables as `$variable`

Comment: make sure the `admin` directory has write permission for the user running the webserver process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function ip(){if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])){$ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];}else if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])){$ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];}else{$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];}return $ip;}
    $ip = ip();

    $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s A");
    $emailField = $_GET['Email'];
    $issueField = $_GET['issue'];
    $ticketField = $_GET['Ticket'];
    $ip = $ip;
    $date = $date;
    $file = 'admin/logs.php';
    $lines = file($file);
    $all_lines = implode('',$lines);
    $entry = str_replace('<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">endtable()</script><script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">copyright()</script>','  <tr>
        <td><div id="logleft"></div></td>
        <td><div id="logmid"><center>'.$emailField.'</center></div></td>
        <td><div id="logmid"><center>'.$ip.'</center></div></td>
        <td><div id="logmid"><center>'.$issueField.'</center></div></td>
        <td><div id="logmid"><center>.'.$ticketField.'</center></div></td>
        <td><div id="logright"></div></td>
    </tr>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">endtable()</script><script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">copyright()</script>',$all_lines);
    $fp = fopen($file,'w'); 
    $fw = fwrite($fp,$entry);
    fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you read documentation [about strings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) in PHP? Change quotes in your strings: ' -> " and " -> '. Or you can use [concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

P.S. use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents) for read whole file

P.P.S. use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents) for write whole file

P.P.P.S. And show us original of your purpose. This code looks like that you have made wrong decision.

Comment: Not really sure what you were saying in your PPPS, however the previous person had helped me, thanks, though!